# Write specific css code for mozila browser

Tags: css

I have written CSS code as follows

```
  div.itemFacebookButton {float:right;margin:-9px 0 0 0;}
```

But in Mozilla the facebook like button is aligned below the other social buttons.
When I put margin -14px then all buttons come in line in Mozilla, but it disturbs the alignment in Chrome.

Then I decided to write specific code for Mozilla. Below is what I tried but it's not working. What's wrong with my code.

```
 -moz-div.itemFacebookButton { float:right; margin:-14px 0 0 0; !important; }
```

Comment: This could help you http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/#Firefox

Comment: Before you go down the road of browser specific styling, have you tried using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), or failing that a reset stylesheet?

Comment: @Alohci You should NOT use a reset or Modernizer to fix one issue. This alignment issue is common to Firefox but, unfortunately, I am not at a place where I can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.itemFacebookButton { float:right; margin:-9px 0 0 0; } 

@-moz-document url-prefix() {  
   div.itemFacebookButton { float:right; margin:-14px 0 0 0; }
}
```

Comment: in your css file, where you have the rest of your rules

Answer (score 0):

There is no `-moz-div` selector, but there are [other Gecko-specific CSS (pseudo) selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions#Pseudo-elements_and_pseudo-classes). You can combine them with normal selectors to create Mozilla-specific rules since browsers ignore the entire rule if it contains at least one selector unsupported by them (it's the standard behavior of CSS error processing and partial implementations). For example, you can write your selector like

```
:moz-any-link, div.itemFacebookButton {float:right;margin:-14px 0 0 0; !important;}
```

But probably the better solution will be to examine the style of the button that causes browsers inconsistence and to rewrite/simplify it, so that it would be not necessary to use browser-specific hacks.